# Sorting a Dictionary by Nested Key

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider a dict of the following form:

```
dic = {
    "First": {
        3: "Three"
    },
    "Second": {
        1: "One"
    },
    "Third": {
        2:"Two"
    }
}
```

I would like to sort it by the nested dic key `(3, 1, 2)`

I tried using the lambda function in the following manner but it returns a "KeyError: 0"

`dic = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])`

The expected output would be:

```
{
    "Second": {
        1: "One"
    },
    "Third": {
        2: "Two"
    },
    "First": {
        3:"Three"
    }
}
```

In essence what I want to know is how to designate a nested key independently from the main dictionary key.

Comment: Dictionaries can't be sorted.

Comment: What would the expected output be if the nested dicts contained more than one key each? For example, `{"first": {3: "three", 1:"one"}, "second": {2:"two"}}`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort the dictionary's nested keys, then iterate over / use those keys?

Comment: @ScottHunter, As of Python 3.7, dictionaries are ordered, so in principle they can be sorted. Now as for whether it's a _good idea_ to sort them, is another question entirely...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the lambda function, `x` is a key-value pair, `x[1]` is the value, which is itself a dictionary. `x[1].keys()` is its keys, but it needs to be turned into a list if you want to get its one and only item by its index. Thus:

```
sorted(dic.items(), key = lambda x: list(x[1].keys())[0])
```

which evaluates to:

```
[('Second', {1: 'One'}), ('Third', {2: 'Two'}), ('First', {3: 'Three'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {'First': {3: 'Three'}, 'Second': {1: 'One'}, 'Third': {2: 'Two'}}
sorted_list = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x:list(x[1].keys())[0])
sorted_dict = dict(sorted_list)
print(sorted_dict)
```

You need to get the keys for the nested dictionary first and then convert them into list and sort over its first index. You will get a sorted list. All you need to convert this list to dictionary using `dict()`. I hope that helps. This snippet works for python3.